# How can I write a function that reverses the order of a list without creating a new variable?

Tags: list

This is what I tried:

```
def reverse(given_list):
    """Reverses the order of a list (does not create a new object; simply reverses the order of the list.

    >>> r = ["Mario", "Bowser", "Luigi"]
    >>> reverse(r)
    >>> r
    ["Luigi", "Bowser", "Mario"]

    """
    given_list = sorted(given_list, key = given_list.index, reverse = True)

list_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
reverse(list_1)
print(list_1)
```

However, `list_1` remains unchanged when I run this function. How can I get my function to generate the output as shown in the docstring?
Please help.

Comment: What programming language are you using ? Do include it as a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `given_list` as a result of your method and use that in your `print` statement. E.g.:

```
def reverse(given_list):
    given_list = sorted(given_list, key = given_list.index, reverse = True)
    return given_list

list_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list_1_reversed = reverse(list_1)
print(list_1_reversed)
```

When giving `list_1` as a parameter to the method, a copy will be created and used. So this question is about the **scope of variables**. You can find information on scope of variables in your favorite book about python or via googling.